# Finding the Fourier transform of a function from random matrix theory

Tags: fourier-transform

[equation from random matrix theory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssw7i.png)

$$R_O(x) = 1- \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}+\left[\int_{1}^{\infty}dz\frac{\sin(xz)}{z}\right]\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac {\sin(x)} x\right)$$

I need to calculate the Fourier transform, but I don't know how to do it. Help me, please!

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.SE. Here we are encouraged to use mathjax typesetting. I made attempt to help you rewrite question image with this typesetting. Also please write any attempts you have made at solving the problem.

Comment: hello! Thanks! I tried to calculate in Mathematica but did not get the result(